# UWP apps - communicate across devices

Tags: sockets, uwp, ipc

We need to build a UWP app which will run on a desktop (which works like a server) and another UWP app which will run on tablets (which works like a client). All these will be in the same local network. The server app will contain some images, videos, 3D models (some of them can be large files around 100 MB or more) and when a button is clicked on that app we need to send that image/video/model to the client app on the tablet. We started researching on the options of doing that and these are the main options we found.

- App services - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service
- Sockets - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets
- Share contract (not sure whether this is available across devices, have to read more) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/

We are planning to create some samples with these options and see what we can do with each option. In the mean time would like to get any ideas from the experts about Pros and Cons of using each of these methods to send data from one UWP app to the other. Also please let me know if I have missed any other options that we can try.

Comment: UWP App services could not be used to provides server for other client. The better way is using WCF as server for your uwp client.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew thanks. But when I read the App services, Sockets articles, it looks like I can share data between two devices. Actually it doesn't have to be a server. One device (UWP app) needs to share some of the data it has with the other devices. We need to be able to distribute the app through Microsoft store. Hence looking for UWP options. I have seen there are options to to distribute a WPF also to store after bridging to UWP. But felt better to do UWP app directly.

Comment: App services are UWP apps that provide services to other UWP apps, the apps should be install in the same device. AppService cannot be accessed across domains.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew Thanks. Yes realized that after reading a bit and trying some samples. Actually we will have to use the Remote Systems (with App services) https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/RemoteSystems